# Log In With Stack Exchange. Why was this added?

Tags: discussion, login

I see a new feature on any login page for Stack Exchange sites called Log In With StackExchange. I wonder why this was added? I thought that OpenID was deemed a better plan and the whole thing was dealt with and no need to put more work on it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SE login still uses OpenID -- Stack Exchange is beta-testing acting as an [OpenID provider](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91039/help-us-test-and-vet-stackid-stack-exchange-openid):

> The experience has never been really stellar.  You click a link, end up on a new page on a new site, with Stack Overflow (or Stack Exchange) dwarfed by MyOpenID's logo... it's a tad confusing for the not so tech savvy user.
>
> Plus MyOpenID keeps [having](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88451/myopenid-account-mysteriously-vanished) [issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71584/login-via-myopenid-does-not-work) .  Right now, for instance, their Captcha is forcing you to waste an extra click during signup.
>
> To this end we're introducing [`openid.stackexchange.com`](https://openid.stackexchange.com/), our own (**beta**) OpenID provider.

Comment: Surely most people have a Google account or can just get one. Is StackExchange really big enough to become an OpenId provider?