# What is "login with stack exchange"?

Tags: discussion, support, login, stack-exchange-openid

What is the new login item "Login with StackExchange?" Can we now have stackexchange accounts in the traditional way of accounts? (But doesn't that defeat the point of OpenId (one account across sites)?)

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92230/log-in-with-stack-exchange-why-was-this-added) - they're [testing their own OpenID provider](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91039/help-us-test-and-vet-stackid-stack-exchange-openid).