# My OpenID is not working properly

Tags: support, openid, login, myopenid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Login via MyOpenID does not work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71584/login-via-myopenid-does-not-work)

When I try to log in using my OpenID the following happens:

- I click "log in", and get redirected to myopenid.com
- Enter credentials ... redirect back to Stack Overflow, where the response is:

  > Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
  >   Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.
- When I then use the "More OpenID options..."  and enter my OpenID manually, everything works and I get logged in.

Can someone else confirm this behaviour? I guess this may happen, because my OpenID contains several dots (something like http://this.is.my.id.myopenid.com)

Is this a bug on the Stack Exchange network? (It's reproducible on all the sites: Meta, Cooking, etc.)

Comment: The point is not that it is not supported any more (I am here and logged in :) but the issue that I always have to fill in my full openid-url into "more options" menu to successfully log in because the standard procedure does not work for me.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Rollback transaction.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71584/login-via-myopenid-does-not-work I am guessing you have a period in your myopenid account name.

Comment: thank you -- and damn, i searched for that but didn't find any posts on this. Guess I'm an early user then ^__^

Comment: @Peter incorrect, see 1st comment on q by op