# Problem logging into stackoverflow with MyOpenId

Tags: support, login, myopenid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Login via MyOpenID does not work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71584/login-via-myopenid-does-not-work)

I can't log into www.stackoverflow.com using MyOpenId. Why not?

When I try, I get the following error message from StackOverflow:

```
Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response
```

Going to www.myopenid.com and looking at the log, I see:

```
Recent Activity
When            IP Address  Event
0 minutes ago   121.44.X.X  Approve for http://stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate/
```

So there is no error on the www.myopenid.com side.

Also I can log into stackoverlow using Google or Facebook succesfully, just not MyOpenId.

Any advice anyone?

Comment: You can't really go from "MyOpenID logged the event" straight to "there is no error on the www.myopenid.com side" -- they could be sending an invalid reply. Which would also explain why Google and Facebook logins work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, sorry for not noticing this, but I found the answer to my question here:

- [Login via MyOpenID does not work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71584/login-via-myopenid-does-not-work)

I did do a search for a previous answer before I posted, but somehow I missed this one. I only noticed this post, after I posted my question. I am one of those early adopters of myopenid whose id contains a dot in it, so I am affected by this issue.

While I understand that this is MyOpenId's fault and not Stackoverflow's fault, I suggest that Stackoverflow could do a better job in detecting the issue when it occurs and providing a more helpful error message.